# How could I have failed this review audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, revisions

Recently I was reviewing this [post](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/430866) and I got result as failed.

What I observed as per this one post was:

- The original poster provided instructions.
- The original poster provided how to access the instructions.

Based on this above points I provided “no action needed”

Once I got the error I got the comment:

> Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new
>   content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have
>   something new to contribute.

As the first post review, reviewer will view only one answer so for me there was no option to flag/identify it as duplicate.

Kindly let me know where/how I have failed the review test?

Comment: 1) You should always verify the content you are reviewing actually exists.  2) I see the following message "Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully" so to indicate "no action is needed" on spam isn't the correction action.  3) Additionally the answer is a comment and does not provide enough information to answer the proposed question so "no action" for that reason alone was incorrect.

Comment: @Ramhound I flagged the original (downvoted) answer as "This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.". It was subsequently deleted. It wasn't spam and the naswer wasn't a comment. It was just a poor answer that was basically a copy of another one (that was posted 11 days earlier). So it got deleted.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Alright;  Alright so my justification for an action might be different then other people's justification.  I suppose my point is that "no action" was the correct action to take.  which is the reason I suggest making sure its a real answer/question before clicking 'no action".

Comment: 1) The "identified as possible spam" notice is often incorrect, but it's also often used on audit questions when it doesn't make sense, so it's a heads up. 2) Without punctuation, it's hard to make sense of the answer, so at least an edit would have been warranted (per JakeGould). 3) The question asks about character replacement and the answer describes deletion, so it doesn't answer ther question. 4) It duplicates another (but complete) answer (per DavidPostill). FYI, selection of audit posts & expected action is automated based on previous user actions rather than the system applying logic.